# Phidget Interface Kit not being detected

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently attempted to get the phidget interface kit working on a second system... I believe I have followed the same steps as I did before by installing from these links (in to a sandbox directory):

```
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgetspp_c_api.html 
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgets_py_api.html 
http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/phidgets_ros.html#InterfaceKit_ROS_API
```

All three packages "made" correctly (or at least without errors).

lsusb shows that the interface kit is being read:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06c2:0045 Phidgets Inc. (formerly GLAB) PhidgetInterface Kit 8-8-8
```

However, when running "`roslaunch phidgets_ros interface_kit.launch`", I receive this error:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1357252527.824527] No serial number specified. This node will connect to the first interface kit attached.
```

I have tested the interface kit itself on a known working system, and it seems to function just fine. It seems that for some reason, the interface kit is not being detected or picked up on the second system.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51405/phidget-interface-kit-not-being-detected/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The phidgets use a serial number which is used for communication. With lsusb -v you can see this. This number should probably be changed in the launch file (the documentation is not clear about this).
interface_kit/<device_serial_number OR user_defined_name>/sensor/<port_number>

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-01-04**:
This is the code for the launch file:

```
<launch>
<node name="interface_kit" pkg="phidgets_ros" type="interface_kit.py" output="screen">
    <!-- <param name="name" type="str" value="my_interface_kit"/> -->
```

-->

```
</node>
```

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-01-04**:
The serial number of the device is 116807... when I un-comment and change the launch file to this:

-->  
I get an error stating

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-01-04**:
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[interface_kit-1]: started with pid [14487]

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-01-04**:
But, the interface kit (physical device) is actually attached.
I also made this modification on the known working machine and it works just fine there... any suggestions?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-01-04**:
Did you change the rights on the usb port? There is a udev rule in the phidgets software package, if I remember it correctly.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-01-04**:
Apparently that was it.
I had to re-run this line:
export USB_DEVFS_PATH=/dev/bus/usb
Thank you!